# How to get user data through JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, richfaces

How would I get information out of my website visitors using JSF (PrimeFaces or RichFaces)? I believe to get the session and the IP would be fairly easy.
I there any part in JSF to get user information for statistical purposes? Some kind of "bunch including it all"?

Comment: What do you need to log? Maybe google analytics or Piwik is enough

Comment: Google Analytics is nice, but I would like to collect the data myself. Mainly for research and study purposes. Therefore, it would be nice to retrieve the biggest possible data.

Comment: Check Piwik if you want it private. Turn on access logging on the server, and import to piwik nightly. Or include a little script in all pages and import in realtime. Don't know of anything specifically for jsf, but also don't know what would be relevant other than what you can already import to piwik